# Troubles trying to start two asynchronous tasks.

Tags: android-asynctask

I want to start two Async Tasks but the second will not start until the first has completed.

From what I've googled, people usually suggest this approach:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);
new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);
```

However, I need to instantiate them separately and also keep the handles of the task's (to pass messages for example). Therefore, I SORT OF do this:

```
onStart() 
{
  taskA = new MyAsyncTask(paramsA);
  taskB = new MyAsyncTask(paramsB);
}

onButtonPress()
{
  taskA.execute();
  taskB.execute();
}
```

Edit:
I've noticed that taskB does not actually start executing until taskA completes (which runs a tcp/ip server so it takes a long time). I cannot figure out why. Any thoughts or comments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that, depending on your version of Android, all `AsyncTask` subclasses may be using the same thread, so you can only do one at a time.  There are two ways around this:

1. Use `Runnable` instead of `AsyncTask`
2. Replace one call to `execute` with `executeOnExecutor(Executor.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)`

Clearly, try #2 first - it's less of a code change.  But if that doesn't work pretty quickly, I'd switch to #1.  In that case, you don't have to worry about how Android might change in the future.

If you want more details about the threading model for `AsyncTask`, have a look at the [Android doc entry](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried #2 but 'Executor.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR' won't pass compile for some reason. I'll look into #1 Tomorrow or so. Anyone has a suggestion on a good Runnable example?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that `executeOnExecutor` is 3.0+, so I don't think there's a way to use `AsyncTask` and have it be version independent.  I ended up using `Runnable` for my code.  The only real trick there is getting your result back on the UI thread.  In my case, I pass the worker thread's object a `Handler`.  Then when the worker thread is finished (or wants to update progress), it can call `Handler.post()`.  I'm not sure if there's a more elegant way to solve that problem, but at least it works.

Comment: #1 Works like a charm :) Thanks a ton Todd!!